# How to Deploy ASP.NET Web Application with SQL Server in Microsoft Azure

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, azure

I have Microsoft Azure account, I don't know how to deploy my project in Microsoft Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a complete tutorial how to deploy an ASP.NET web application including an Azure SQL database.

[Create an ASP.NET MVC app with auth and SQL DB and deploy to Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/)

You mentioned Visual Studio 2010 in your tags. I do not remember the support of VS2010 for Azure. But I know it is very good in Visual Studio 2015, even in the [free Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us).

Comment: @user2369568 if you like the answer, mark it as answer ;-)